# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

Tags: java, apache, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using IntelliJ and I am trying to use the FileUtils.copyFile() method. When I use that method I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
e/commons/io/FileUtils
```

Here is the code that uses the copy file method:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
    try {
         File destJAR = new File("c:/X-Dock/MP3Player.jar");
         File playerJAR = new File(MP3Player); //"MP3Player" is a string that is defined earlier.
         FileUtils.copyFile(playerJAR, destJAR);
    }catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I imported the Apache Commons JAR "commons-io-2.4" into the IntelliJ project by going to

```
File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> Java -> "commons-io-2.4.jar"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That error implies that `commons-io-2.4.jar` is not on your classpath at runtime. How are you running your program?

Comment: @ruakh I build an executable jar file and run it. Or I just run it from intelliJ. I imported commons-io-2.4.jar just like many other external libraries

Comment: When you run your executable jar, how are you specifying the classpath?

Comment: @ruakh I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by that. Can you explain

Comment: The build process (probably) does not embed `commons-io-2.4.jar` inside your own jar-file. Rather, it expects that `commons-io-2.4.jar` will be available at run-time; so your own jar-file relies on it, but doesn't supply it. The way you make it available at runtime is to include it in your classpath. For example, if you're running `java`, you would use the `-cp` argument to specify the classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to resolve your problem.
[image]

or you can edit configuration file

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```